# List View Group By not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view

I've got a list and I've created a view that shows all items and groups by "Created By". But when I load that view I can't see the list items. I only get the "working on it" message.

[image]

This grouping works on other lists and when I expand the group section they generate a post request.
But on my list view, when I expand, no request is made. There are no JS errors.

And if I change the column that I'm grouping by it still does not work.
Any Thoughts?

Update:
I found out that if I change the style of that view to default, it works. If the style is "Shaded" it does not. Any idea why?
The shaded style works for other listviews.

[image]

Comment: strange. Any records with nulls? Do you have a JSLink attached to the view?

Comment: No JSLink for that view.

Comment: Looks like you found a bug. If the Group title isn't populated, that's prob what it uses to query and craps out.

Comment: try to delete & re-create view..

Comment: Got this problem for some IE11 users in SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 1):

View grouping is not available whit asynchronous loading. It should be disabled when you are using item groups.

Comment: Hi Luca, Please be elaborate and add more details about the solution for better understanding of all.

Comment: This resolved an issue for me where a web part using "Group By" was not filtering the groups correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by going to the view settings and under the group by tab, select the groups to be expanded and not collapsed by default.

Comment: if you look at screenshot provided by @txugo. it is already expanded

Answer (score -2):

Ensure that '`Enable Asynchronous Update`' is enabled for the List View WebPart.